# ROUND not working when row_number() function is present

Tags: mysql, sql, row-number, ranking-functions

This is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do.
I am trying to rank users based on how many miles they walked overall.

This data is stored in the table called `walks`. Every time a user makes a walk, an entry is added.

```
create temporary table walks
(
    id       int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    user_id  int unsigned             not null,
    miles_walked float unsigned default '0' not null,
    date date not null
);
```

To fill in the table:

```
insert into walks (user_id, miles_walked, date)
values
    (1, 10.1, '2022-12-20'),
    (2, 60.2, '2022-12-21'),
    (3, 30.3, '2022-12-22'),
    (1, 0.4, '2022-12-23'),
    (2, 10.5, '2022-12-24'),
    (3, 10.6, '2022-12-25'),
    (1, 40.7, '2022-12-26'),
    (2, 80.8, '2022-12-27'),
    (3, 30.9, '2022-12-28');
```

```
select * from walks;
```

[image: The result of the above query]

```
select user_id,
       SUM(miles_walked) as miles_walked_total,
       ROUND(SUM(miles_walked), 1) as miles_walked_total_rounded,
       row_number() over (order by SUM(miles_walked) desc)  as miles_rank
from walks
group by user_id
order by user_id
```

[image: The result of the above query]

As you can see, rounding is **WRONG** for users with id 2 and 3. What happened? Like I said, this is a simplified example. In my real case, not just rounding, but the ranking is wrong for the whole set when I use functions like `ROUND` and `LENGTH`:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SUM(LENGTH(reports.comments)) + SUM(report_items.report_items_characters_number)) DESC) AS ranking
```

Comment: Don't use imprecise floating point, use a decimal type.  Then you don't need to round

Comment: Unless I'm missing something this is a bug.  What does select version() show?

Comment: @ysth This is a simplified version. In the real case, we actually track meters walked. Then we convert them to miles.

Comment: @ysth select version();

8.0.22

Comment: Tested in mysql version 5.1.1, Its working fine !

Comment: I can't duplicate it in 8.0.30 https://dbfiddle.uk/y04TcMlp
I suspect it's a bug that's been fixed.

Comment: @SouhailV I suspect you are looking at a client version, not your server version. MySQL before version 8 didn't even have row_number.  Do `select version();` to see your server version

Comment: @ysth I guess I will upgrade MySQL and see if everything works in the real scenario. I didn't even start thinking that it could be a MySQL bug - I thought I was doing something wrong.

Comment: But definitely avoid float; there's almost never a good reason to use that.  Then your problem goes away

Comment: @ysth yep, I used it just for this example. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed your comment about meters

Comment: @ysth It works!!! Thank you very much! Do you want to post an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @SouhailV Thank you too for checking it in your env!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't duplicate it in 8.0.30: https://dbfiddle.uk/y04TcMlp

I suspect it's a bug that's been fixed.  I recommend you upgrade.